# replace a tag but not everything in between tags

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

Lets say I have a long string and I want to remove one "< a >" tag and this is what I have already tried:

```
$text= preg_replace('~<a[\s\S]*?'.$aString.'[\s\S]*?/a>~','',$text);
```

As you can see with this line it removes **everything** from the first "< a" to the one that satisfies the condition.

How do I rewrite it that it only searches inside one opening and closing a tag?

In another words to make myself clear: I have a long text that might or might not have many "< a" tags. I need to remove any of them that contains a specific string. This string is created dynamically. With the code above I tell the program to search for "< a" and remove everything until it finds the $aString and then to the closing "a >" tag which is not what I want. I want it to remove only the tag that contains $aString.

**UPDATE**: a simple str_replace wouldn't do the trick because it fails the part that "[\s\S]*?" achieve that's why I put "[\s\S]*?" there. As I said the text inside the tag contains $aString and by that I meant: it might be:

```
<a class='blah' style='blah' $aString title='blah'>blahblahblah</a>
```

or

```
<a class='notblah' style='notblah' $aString>blah</a>
```

or

```
<a> $aString</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

> `'~<a[\s\S]*?'.$aString.'[\s\S]*?/a>~'`
> How do I rewrite it that it only searches inside one opening and closing a tag?

A *negative lookahead* [assertion](https://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.assertions.php) can effect that `<a…` is matched so that no other `<a` is contained in the match. You'd replace the subpattern `<a[\s\S]*?` with `<a((?!<a)[\s\S])*?`.
Also you can simplify the expression a little by setting the [modifier](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php) *s* (*PCRE_DOTALL*) and changing `[\s\S]` to `.`.

```
$text = preg_replace('~<a((?!<a).)*?'.$aString.'.*?/a>~s', '', $text);
```